# Did Gotama (the Buddha) practise incest?

Tags: papanca, fake, news

The [Dasaratha Jātaka](https://suttacentral.net/ja461/en/rouse?reference=none&highlight=false) says Gotama (our current Buddha) was Rama in a past life and his wife (Gotama's son's Rahula's mother Yaśodharā) was his sister Sita in the same past life. In this past life, Rama appeared to marry his sister Sita (who, according to the translation, became Rama's queen-consort). Then later Rama was reborn as Gotama and Sita was reborn as Yaśodharā (Rahula's mother).

Was Gotama's marriage to Yaśodharā an example of 'incest'?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it does not clearly specify the intent. Are you looking for the dictionary definition of the English word "incest"? Is this an invitation to discuss the status of jatakas in Khuddaka Nikaya? Are you using this example to explore whether the concept of personal identity carries across multiple lives? All of the above? Not clear, and as written, somewhat provocative.

Comment: It was posted further to [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/39482/254) and presumably that question.

Comment: The Buddha clearly reaches not to latch onto any marks. But if we keep running around the clinging aggregates like a dog bound to a post we are going nowhere except losing our precious time. Just contrary to the transcendent teaching. It can be gratifying for folls like me to check out some enlightening answers though.

Comment: Some folks in here really write awesome answers. Every once in a while I stumble upon enlightening QA.

Answer (score 1):

A worldling without a knowledge of past lives would not see that as "incest".

[SN 15.14](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.14/en/sujato)

> At Sāvatthī.
> “Mendicants, transmigration has no known beginning.
> It’s not easy to find a sentient being who in all this long time has not previously been your mother.
> Why is that?
> Transmigration has no known beginning.
> This is quite enough for you to become disillusioned, dispassionate, and freed regarding all conditions.”

Comment: The Buddha had no knowledge of "past lives". Pubbe nivasa does not mean past lives. Also, there are suttas, such as SN 22.70, that say there are Arahants without knowledge of pubbe nivasa. Also there are suttas such as DN 1 that say Eternalist puthujjana have knowledge of past nivasa. As for this answer, it does not answer the question but seems to support the idea the Buddha approved of & engaged in incest.

Comment: `this answer ... seems to support the idea the Buddha approved of & engaged in incest` That may be your interpretation of it but I think that's nonsense. Also -- and this a separate topic and still not intended as an apology -- "incest" is seen by modern societies as a taboo or bad thing, a crime, and llegal as a marriage, but I doubt that was also so in ancient societies, where royalty might intermarry.

Comment: again this comment supports the idea of family intermarriage. since people have known for a long time family intermarriage causes biological & mental disorders, this comment gives the impression the Buddha lacked omniscience or at the very least did not understand the results of such kamma.

Comment: `family intermarriage causes biological & mental disorders` The OP says a "past life", not a close "blood" relationship. `this comment gives the impression the Buddha lacked omniscience` Gotama wasn't "the Buddha" when he was married, nor marry his (blood) sister.

Comment: no no no..... the Buddha purportedly spoke the Jataka & SN 15.14. Surely if the Buddha was aware of this incest he would have spoke against it rather than exalt it leading to Buddhahood.

Comment: Do you figure the Jataka has an intent, a desired effect on or lesson for the audience?